# sending http request from PLSQL, receiving it by Spring Integration and replying

Tags: spring, plsql, httprequest, httpresponse, spring-integration

I'm trying to send a http request from PLSQL. It works fine.

```
HttpRequest := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST (url => v_http_url, METHOD => 'POST');
utl_http.set_header(HttpRequest, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' );
utl_http.set_header(HttpRequest, 'Content-Length', 64);
utl_http.write_line(HttpRequest, 'some string');
Httpresp := utl_http.get_response(HttpRequest);
utl_http.end_request(HttpRequest);
utl_http.end_response(Httpresp);
```

The Spring Integration side:

```
<int:channel id="inputChannel" />
<int:channel id="outputChannel" />

<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="inputChannel"
    reply-channel="outputChannel" supported-methods="POST" name="/req"
    message-converters="MyRequestConverter"
    request-payload-type="MyRequest">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator input-channel="inputChannel"
    method="getMessage" ref="dbmock"></int:service-activator>
```

I've created MyRequestConverter with methods:

```
MyRequest readInternal(Class<? extends MyRequest > _class, HttpInputMessage message) throws IOException
void writeInternal(MyRequest request, HttpOutputMessage message)
```

My service method looks like this:

```
public Object getMessage(@Headers Map<String, Object> headers, @Payload MyRequest payload)
```

The problem is PLSQL site doesn't get response - it waits endlessly. When I comment

```
Httpresp := utl_http.get_response(HttpRequest)
```

PLSQL procedure is executed succesfully. Moreover I get exception that there's no converter for java.lang.String.

Is there any way to use MyRequestConverter in reversed direction?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't know if it matters but the [examples given in the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_http.htm#i1013177) only have either `END_RESPONSE` or `END_REQUEST`, not both (use `END_RESPONSE` if you have used `GET_RESPONSE` before).

Comment: I've tried using only end_response with no luck. The timeout occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the content-length to 64, but only sending 11 bytes. The server is waiting for more data.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have a clue it's that important.